# Expect, find files with timestamp

Tags: tcl, expect

I have folder with files as below:

```
RBS_delete20150518-170641.xml
RBS_delete20150517-160545.xml
...
```

I'm using `expect` program, but can't get regexp working on date stamp:

```
if {[file exists /home/ARNE/ARNE/SCRIPTS/RBS_delete[0-9].xml]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file exists` doesn't support `regexp` patterns. You can use `glob`.

```
set myfiles [ glob -nocomplain "/home/ARNE/ARNE/SCRIPTS/*.xml" ]
if {[llength $myfiles]!=0} {
puts "Following XML files found  : "
foreach fname $myfiles {
    puts $fname; # Now you can process these elements as per your wish
    if {[regexp {RBS_delete\d+\-\d+\.xml} $fname]} {
        puts " file name pattern matched"
    }
}
} else {
puts "No XML files available"
}
```